# On DrillUp Set Series Name Failing

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

We had to make a variant of a drillable chart not using the `drilldown.js` plugin due to other issues with having a stacking bar chart. I can get the drill down and the drill up working correctly except for the issue of the `series.name` for our initial 2 series not being reset. On drill we use this code (taken from Fusher's answer [here](http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=13294)):

```
function setChart(name, categories, data, color, level, type) {
    chartMainLoc.xAxis[0].setCategories(categories);
    var dataLen = data.length;

    chartMainLoc.series[0].remove();
    if (dataLen === 1) {
        chartMainLoc.series[0].remove();
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLen; i++) {
        chartMainLoc.addSeries({
            type: type,
            name: name,
            color: colors[i],
            data: data[i],
            level: level
        });
    }
}
```

On drill down this works. On drill up I am left with `Series 1 - xxx` in the tooltip. What am I missing to make this set the series name correctly back to the original?

Using HC 3.0.10. Live [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8XqMp/13/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the same `name` variable for both options. I guess there should be `dataName` and `dataName2`. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8XqMp/15/

So in short:

- set name param to be an array when you call setChart()
- in setChart() loop over `name` variable

Comment: Good grief. So simple...will test it out.